# How can my Cloud Run accept traffic only from Cloud scheduler and Google Directoy API

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-directory-api

How do I setup Cloud Run to only accept requests from Cloud Scheduler and Directory API?

I am using flask on Cloud Run that has 2 primary functions:

1. Send a watch (HTTP) request (triggered by Cloud Scheduler) to the google Directory API
2. Receives update (HTTP request) from the google Directory API

Currently my application on Cloud Run works without issue when "allUsers" is given the permission "Invoke Cloud Run."

To make it more secure:

1. I removed "allUsers" from the Cloud Run permissions
2. Gave Cloud Scheduler a service account that has the ability to invoke the Cloud Run
3. Added the Directory API service account to the Cloud Run and gave it the ability to invoke Cloud Run

Cloud scheduler invokes the Cloud Run without issue, but when an update is received from the Directory API, I keep getting: `The request was not authenticated. Either allow unauthenticated invocations or set the proper Authorization header. Read more at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/authenticating`

Documentation for the directory api requests I am using: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/watch

Comment: I guess that Directory API use an access token and not an identity token (OIDC). I fear that you need to build an intermediary layer, with a Cloud Function for example or Cloud Endpoint.

Comment: But then wouldn't the issue just move to the function or endpoint?

Comment: Cloud Endpoints is simply a gateway that check the quotas (if defined) and the authorization (if defined) and forward/translate the request to the correct service. For Cloud Functions, I know an hack to call it with an access token (and not with an idToken with you put it in private) but you are limited to 10 call per 100 seconds